# Check for registry key value using powershell script

Tags: powershell, registrykey

I need help to create a PowerShell script that will check for registry key only (not value) and will add registry key in case of absence of Registry key in the computer.

I've been able to add the tag using the script

```
 reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Tanium\Tanium Client\Sensor Data\Tags" /v Test
```

But when trying to search the key using

```
Test-Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Tanium\Tanium Client\Sensor Data\Tags\Test'
```

It is showing False. No values need to be assigned to the key 'Test'. Just need a script that will return the value if the 'Test' tag has been created or not. If not, will be able to execute the script.

The below script is not capturing existence of the key 'Test'

```
$x =Get-ChildItem -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Tanium\Tanium Client\Sensor Data\Tags' 
if($x -eq "Test") {
    write-host("Key is There")
}
Else {
    reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Tanium\Tanium Client\Sensor Data\Tags" /v Test
}
```

Need help to get the correct checking criteria.

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question (and [How do I ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822), if relevant).

Comment: `$x` is not a string...

Answer (score 1):

`Test-Path` can only check for key, not for it's properties.

For registry entries, *key* means the folder you can see using Registry Editor. *Properties* are the ones you can see on the right-hand side:

[image: regedit screenshot showing key and property]

To get the property you can use `Get-ItemProperty` cmdlet:

```
$regEntryPath = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Tanium\Tanium Client\Sensor Data\Tags'

# Grab the property
$property = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $regEntryPath).Test
# Test if property exists
$null -ne $property

# Should return true
```

Let's also test whether the above works correctly for non-existing properties:

```
# Now check for non-existing property
$property2 = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $regEntryPath).NonExisting
$null -ne $property2

# Should return false
```

Comment: It is returning True and Fales for existing and non-existing values respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Test-Path` instead of `Get-ChildItem` if you want to test if a registry key exists.

Also, better use `New-Item` to create the key if it does not exist yet instead of using reg.exe. Many group policies refuse the use of registry editing tools like reg.exe.

Try

```
$regPath = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Tanium\Tanium Client\Sensor Data\Tags\Test'
if ((Test-Path -Path $regPath)) {
    Write-Host "Key exists"
}
else {
    New-Item -Path $regPath
}
```

Of course, doing this in the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE hive, you need to have admin permissions.